# Icon missing in tasks witcher and window, (but not in app launcher nor Task Manager)

Tags: kde, icons, flatpak, fedora

For several but not all apps (installed with flatpak), there are icons missing in the task switcher and the application window itself. Yet these icons are available in the application launcher and on the Task Manager. Example:

[image]

The icon in the `.desktop` seems to be set correctly (`com.axosoft.GitKraken` in this case).

I've tried to figure out how icons are resolved. And according to the docs it seems that as soon as any icon is found, regardless of size, it should be used. It seems like an icon is found, as it shows up in some places.

So what causes icons to be missing in one place while available in another? Does the task switcher and the window manager not use the `.desktop` file? And if so, what do they use?

I am using Fedora with KDE Plasma. Apps with missing icons: Slack and Gitkraken. Apps (from flatpak) with working icons: OBS, VLC.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Have the same problem